# Does "defined but never used" variables slow down website speed ReactJS?

Tags: javascript

I have already published a website http://www.roadmapedia.com/ It turns out to be very slow. I am sure that the majority of the time is probably spent loading the javascript stuff I have written.

Here's my thing: I have like 20 different javascript files cause I am using React and have a lot of reusable components. I have loaded the whole semantic ui react package with a script tag already in the root html. Then, if I were to do import {Grid} from "semantic-ui-react" in some of the JS files but never use Grid afterall, will this take a huge toll on the speed?

Comment: Might bloat file size a little bit but shouldn't cause significant performance issues

Comment: which react.js version are u using??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the majority of your site's load time (~75%) is spent waiting for the `chunk.js` file to download. I assume this is some sort of bundle generated by your build process. You can check the network tab of Chrome's Developer Tools, screenshotted below, to get an idea for this. It might be worth investigating your hosting as this is a large load time for a small file on a fast connection.

[image]

It's likely that your build tool will only include the file once. That is, including it for the first time will slightly reduce performance, and thereafter will have no affect. I'd be happy to investigate further if you have more details to share.

Comment: Thank you for that! Yea, chunk.js is indeed whatever my react code compiles too. But now I know I can cut away some of that css I never use, and that weird picture which somehow takes 420ms!